# Выбор языка программирования для дальнейшего изучения

Tags: php, javascript, java, c

Хочу услышать мнение специалистов на счёт выбора языка программирования для изучения в дальнейшем и, что выбрать потом, и стоит так учится как я. На данный момент есть средние знания по вёрстке сайтов, учу: JavaScript, PHP, чистое си без плюсов - после "набития" в си нескольких мегабайт упражнений и освоения простейших алгоритмов, хочу двинуться на Java. Проблема в том, что уже большая каша в голове. Утром делаю сайт, вечером сижу решаю задачки на си. В чём то оно дополняет в общем друг друга синтаксис и так далее. И я не знаю в итоге, что ближе ко мне, создаётся впечатление, что знаешь чуточку везде. Правильно ли так учить? Или надо выбрать один язык и тратить на него всё время не обращая внимание на другие языки программирования или можно параллельно как-то развиваться? Хочется и сайты делать нравится, и на телефон хотелось бы попробовать программировать (я имею в виду Java на Android). Что делать не знаю, уже просто паника.

Comment: я как бы ещё раз выскажусь - языки в программировании вторичны.

Comment: Сколько не слышал - большинство говорят - попал сюда чисто случайно. Хотел писать (например) на JAVA, а стал писать на PHP (C/C++ и т.д.) потому что так судьба сложилась.

Это не слова с какого-нить форума, а слова с различных интервью и умных книжек известных (по крайней мере мне))) людей.

Это, конечно, не относится к тем, кто начал писать на языке, потому что сам его создал (внес большой вклад в развитие). Хотя, может быть, они тоже случайно этим начали заниматься)

Как по мне - лучше везде по чуть-чуть, пока возможность есть, а как определитесь сами - так и в глубь расти можно.

Comment: > Что делать не знаю, уже просто паника(((

В тахих случаях помогает обычно отдых)

Comment: @alexlz, там комментарии кончились.

[Вот тут](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) обнаружил (array — Efficient arrays of numeric values).

А на numpy там ссылка есть.

--

Насчет языков без оператора цикла вообще не понял. Лично я с такой экзотикой не знаком (кроме SQL и др.), хотя принципиально могу представить. 

Вряд ли такой язык на практике годится для массового обучения.

Comment: @avp это была лёгкая провокация. Берёте книжки (можно в и-нет) sicp, htdp. Когда найдёте там **оператор** цикла, сообщите мне.

Comment: @alexlz, если не путаю, то их используют в каких-то курсах MIT?

Рискну предположить, что авторы неявно предполагают наличие определенных знаний "традиционных" способов программирования у студентов, которые смогли поступить в MIT.

Comment: @avp sicp. И то сейчас вроде используется уже питон. А вот насчёт "наличия традиционных знаний" -- это далеко не всегда плюс. Иногда эти знания, точнее навыки -- серьёзный минус.

Кстати аналогичная ситуация была и несколько десятилетий назад, когда покойный Дейкстра утверждал, что студенты, которых обучали программированию при помощи бейсика (или фортрана? -- не помню) -- уже безнадёжны.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Выбор языка программирования для изучения - то же самое что для художника выбирать с чем учиться рисовать - карандаш, гуашь, тушь и т.д. Я например в последнее время решаю олимпиадные задачки, причем делаю так: 1-ую задачу пишу на C++, 2-ую на Delphi, а остальные на PHP.

Просто надо проникаться духу программирования, понимать алгоритмы, ООП и знать всякие теории, как это все происходит, а языки это вторичное.

Comment: Я так и думаю, просто многие мне говорят, что надо выбрать что-то одно, иначе никогда не достигнешь хорошего уровня. Просто иногда чувствуешь себя очень неуверенно из-за того, что каша в голове, накладывается одно на другое. Спасибо за совет, радует, что я не один так думаю.

Comment: хороший уровень кодера и хороший уровень программиста - разные вещи

Comment: @steelhouse посоветую просто большей практики, т.е. если пишешь сайты, пиши сайты, совершенствуйся, изучай php, js, html, css. Навыки программирования хорошо поднимаются с помощью Олимпиадных задач, я например знаю 2 хороших сайта, с задачками: http://codeforces.ru и http://www.e-olimp.com . Попробуй связать виндовс приложение с сайтом, Пробуй связывать с соц сетями. И еще раз повторю - самое главное практика!

Comment: Я считаю, что через при достатке времени в самостоятельном изучении, человек просто обязан пройти через кучу языков и кашу в голове - только так можно получить живое обширное представление о прикладном программировании вообще, технологиях и подходах к решению задач.

Answer (score 5):

Постоянно твержу, что в программировании есть 3 языка, на которых собственно все и держится:

1. Семейка C/C++
2. Java
3. Семейка dot NET, если быть точнее C#

Прогер, который считает себя разработчиком (software developer) - обязан знать 1 из этих языков - это просто **MUST**.

После освоения 1-го из этих языков (я бы даже сказал не освоения, а внедрения в спинной мозг) нужно добавить к своему багажу SQL в одной из 2-х инкарнаций:

1. Oracle PL/SQL
2. Miscrosof Transact SQL

Опосля уже можно перейти к скриптирующим языкам, типа:

1. JavaScript
2. Python
3. PHP
4. Perl
5. VBScript
6. Добавить свой

уже согласно своей специализации.

**P.S.** Впрочем, если прогер считает себя инженером (software engineer) - можно сразу переходить к скриптам и не ломать свой спинной мозг внедрением в него C/C++/Java/C#

Comment: Выражаю свое несогласие с вашим первым утверждением, такое утверждение обычно делают люди начавшие свою жизнь программиста с C/C# . Но увы, мне не охото на данный момент спорить, поэтому примите мои слова как просто, мою точку зрения.

Comment: @Barmaley как всегда об enterprise-ах, а Delphi/Ruby/Python/JS-программисты как всегда недоумевают ))

Comment: как же жили до c# ? что такого на нем держится, извините ? Помрет оно без ms

Comment: @nofate недоумевают потому что они инженеры, а не разработчики - чувствует разницу?

Comment: @Barmaley, Может быть почувствую, если вы приведете четкую разницу между "инженером" и "разработчиком" только безо всяких "инженеры полагаются на инженерные приципы при разработке ПО, исходя из требований бла-бла-бла..." Может быть узнаю, кто я )

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что все у Вас, уважаемый Бармалей, белыми нитками сшито. Как-то неубедительно все. Слишком упрощено.

И откуда такое высокомерное отношение к "скриптовым языкам"? На мой взгляд, Лисп (скриптовый язык!) на порядок сложнее и труднее во внедрении во все мозги, чем Java.

Comment: зато Лисп невероятно логичный язык )

Comment: @IVsevolod

      зато Лисп невероятно логичный язык )

А расшифровать это утверждение можете?

@Barmaley а OCaml вместо C++/Java -- можно?

Comment: По мне так Питон - просто верх логичности ))) И вообще, не трогайте Питон !!! Он в последние пару месяцев вывел работу нашей лаборатории на новый уровень.

Comment: Думается мне, что автор имел ввиду практическую значимость+сложность этих языков.. Аналог соотношения цена/качество. В этом я с ним согласен. Джоел Спольски писал, что каждый программист обязан знать С/С++ со всей своей ссылочной моделью. НУ а человек, освоивший эту ветку, освоит любую другую очень быстро (он приводил примеры про своих сотрудников, которые учили Java за месяц).

Comment: @Carma, вот про знакомство с Си - вполне согласен. Еще можно добавить касательное знакомство с ассемблером (любым) - безумно полезно даже в небольших дозах. А вот польза для общего развития от знакомства с джавой или шарпом - весьма сомнительна.

Comment: @Carma

     НУ а человек, освоивший эту ветку, освоит любую другую очень быстро (он приводил примеры про своих сотрудников, которые учили Java за месяц).

Брехня ((c) С.Краморов в х/ф "Неуловимые мстители"). Примеры освоивших java после освоения C++/java/C# можно не приводить.

@mikillskegg рекомендую MACRO-11 (правда, сам я его не знаю и на нём не писал).

Comment: @mikillskegg - все упирается в практическую значимость языков с точки зрения количества написанного софта, количества если хотите бабок которые крутятся при этих языках. Скрипты при всей их значимости увы не набирают (пока еще) критической массы. Вполне допускаю, что если проект HTML5 не вымрет, то JavaScript имеет неплохие шансы потеснить топ тройку.

@Nofate приведу цитату:

>Development and engineering are based on opposite tenets. Engineering is scientific, quantified, and disciplined, whereas development is random, not based on metrics, and stays away from engineering discipline.

Comment: @Barmaley, что-то мне подсказывает, что вокруг С и С++ (особенно С) в настоящее время бабок совсем немного крутится. С другой стороны, весь веб - это почти сплошные скрипты.

Comment: @mikillskegg скрипты? А что это такое? Вроде как и php -- скрипты, и python (django) -- тоже скрипты. А вроде как и разные.

@Barmaley javascript... кого-то потеснит. А чего это то и дело появляются новыет трансляторы с "чего-то" на javascript?

Comment: @Barmaley, ааа.. так development - это быдлокодерство, а engineering - разработка? )  Тогда, ок. Но первое я вообще не рассматриваю в таком случае. Это временный жизненный этап, из которого надо вырваться поскорее.

Comment: @mikillskegg вы надеюсь не троллите когда говорите, что вокруг C/C++ бабок мало :) Да посмотрите на индекс востребованности и все станет ясно.

@Nofate оч. смешно...

@alexlz давай подождем и посмотрим на судьбу прожекта HTML5, что-то мне подсказывает, что судьба JavaScript решается там

Comment: > SQL в одной из 2-х инкарнаций

Вы перепутали, это не на software developer, это на enterprise architect надо учить.

Comment: @Barmaley вероятно я непонятно выразился. Свою судьбу на ближайшее время javascript уже решил. Заменить его сейчас нечем -- js поддерживают все. Но вот то, что писать будут на чём-нибудь другом, с трансляцией в js, оставляя для js работу backend'а -- это мне кажется более вероятным. Потому как код, увешанный callback'ами производит не самое приятное впечатление.

Comment: @alexlz я тоже вероятно неверно выразился. JS поддерживают все это как-то сильно звучит - его поддерживают только браузеры. Я имел ввиду HTML5 в том контексте что браузерная среда претендует теперь на звание полномасштабной оси. Если претензия будет подкреплена жизнью, то действительно JS получит власть во всех средах. Пока же говорить об этом рано.

Comment: @Barmaley QT поддерживает js, (если можно так выразиться конечно)

Comment: ЯП в мире очень много, и каждый хорош в своей нише, но в моей только недавно начавшийся карьере все идет в том порядке, как автор написал =)

Answer (score 4):

Стив Макконел, автор [этой](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3159814/) прекрасной книги писал, что нужно писать не на языке, а с помощью языка. Думаю с этим сложно поспорить. Однако помнить все тонкости всех языков, чтобы писать эффективный код "для всего и сразу" очень сложно, да и не надо. Тонкости, если о них догадываться, всегда можно подсмотреть.

Однако, если развивать карьеру и расти до архитектора, или тим лида, или чего-то подобного, то придется погружаться в тонкости одних языков, в ущерб других. Причем, это погружение порой доходит не только до уровня языков, а даже до уровня технологий и предметных областей.

Что касается конкретных языков, то думаю, С/С++ идеален для понимания указателей на объекты - не слишком абстрактен как Java и не слишком конкретен как Ассемблер. Знания тут помогут во всех ОО языках. Ну а дальше оставаться универсальным программистом так долго, как только можно. Чему уделять больше внимания при развитии карьеры, тут думаю все решит серия обстоятельств: могут понадобиться деньги срочно и возьмешь за работу, на первом попавшемся языке, и как говорится - понеслась, а может увлечешься какой-то областью науки, и будут требования к языку, может еще что.

Comment: Упрощаете. Один добавочный аспект:

      But when you choose a language, you're also choosing a community. (P. Graham, http://www.paulgraham.com/gh.html)

И не забывайте, языки -- они бывают сильно разные. Очень сильно.

Comment: @alexlz, отчасти это является правдой, отчасти нет. Если ты живешь не в городе по умолчанию, то скорее выбираешь из того что "осталось". В провинциальных городах конференции очень редки, и чаще всего платные, а про работу на экзотических языках типа Go, Erlang, и даже Ruby и Python не приходится и думать. Вот и остается "троица" + web направление. Да есть онлайн курсы, это круто, но это скорее академические знания, нежели опыт коммерческой разработки.

Comment: Посмотрим, что скажет господин кризис.

Comment: >  и даже Ruby и Python

Кстати, у нас в провинциальном городе мы пишем в т.ч и на Ruby. А другая контора пишет на Python.

Answer (score 0):

С языками программирования, практически тоже самое, что и с языками лингвистическими (упс). Выучил английский - другие, например: французский, испанский, итальянский - уже намного легче даются. 
В программировании нечто похожее. Только есть нюанс: смотря с какой парадигмы начинается обучение. Лично я всем рекомендую с ассемблера начинать, это воспитывает в человеке экономность, как бы так сказать, с другой стороны, развивает тенденции к познанию низкоуровневых особенностей, без которых не состоится настоящий специалист и изобретатель.
В отличие от него, человек, начинающий на готовеньком - очень быстро привыкает к сладкому и, как правило, расслабляется и становится "толстым пожирателем гамбургеров".

А в целом и общем, - смотрите сами, к чему вы больше предрасположены. Я просто высказал свою точку зрения.

Comment: Начинать с ассемблера - это круто!

Хотя, кто-то когда-то начинал с машинных кодов и на перфоленте...

Comment: Почему круто? Это нормально.

Comment: @validol, сами с асма начинали?

Comment: Нет, с перфолент и морзянки.

Comment: Спасибо за точку зрения. Я учил ассемблер в институте понятия есть о нём, но не достаточно глубокие, просто основы. На данный момент проблема со временем и возраст (особенно второе) упирается во всё. Я думаю я не один с этим сталкивался, жалею, что раньше не занимался и потерял время.

Comment: @avp Вряд ли здесь есть те, кто начинал с машинных кодов на перфоленте. Экзотика-с. А вот идея начинать с ассемблера -- идея глупая и вредная. Обсуждали уже не раз здесь (лично я начинал изучение программирования как раз с ассемблера). Во времена, когда Кнут писал первый том своего "Искусства программирования" это считалось нормально и правильно. Сейчас -- это "путь асмоламера" (обучение, как за пару недель сэкономить несколько байт на компьютере с 2G+ RAM). Ниша ассемблера невелика и постоянно уменьшается.

Comment: @alexlz, круто - это, конечно, ирония.

Я тоже считаю, что асм, как первый язык не годится. Наверное лучше всего pascal. Хотя есть и шутка, что паскаль это расширенный вариант урезанного алгола.

А вот потом пару-тройку ассемблеров освоить не помешает. Конечно, не для того, чтобы руками на них программы писать, а чтобы архитектуры прочувствовать.

А в идеале писать (совершенная банальность) надо на том языке, который лучше всего для данной задачи подходит. 

Только вот на практике выбор его определяется не столько задачей, сколько твоими познаниями в языках.

Comment: @avp Насчёт паскаля. Толи в этом веке, толи в прошлом один парень писал, что ему пришлось в летнем лагере оболтусов началам программирования обучать. На паскале пытался учить -- не идёт. На питоне -- совсем другая история. Быстро и легко. Контингент -- не самые лучшие ученики.

Comment: @alexlz, Питон это отлично. Особенно если еще знать, какие модули импортировать и какие полезные методы там есть.

Я именно о том, что *начальное обучение* программированию на Python, C# (да, даже, Java) смещает акцент в сторону *использования* библиотек, а не *"изобретения"* структур данных и алгоритмов несколькими примитивными операциями (цикл, выбор, вызов).

Уверен, что половина начавших (и остановившихся на этом) в Питоне не представляют что лежит внутри списка или множества.

Кстати, я обнаружил, что в Python есть array. (Помните генерацию массивов random?) Только еще ничего не пробовал

Comment: @avp

     Кстати, я обнаружил, что в Python есть array.

Точно в Python, а не в numpy?

     (цикл, выбор, вызов).

Для таких вещей надо брать языки без операторов цикла.

Comment: @alexlz, есть такая штука `array` в батарейках. Но для обработки данных в питоне лучше, конечно, использовать `numpy`. Кстати, многие операции в нем по скорости сопоставимы с написанными на Си, при этом многие сложные вещи делаются одной строчкой в коде. Там, кстати, главный объект называется `ndarray`

Comment: В стандартной библиотеке, я имею в виду. Выражение такое,про батарейки. `numpy` туда не входит, ставится отдельно.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/array.html

Comment: Совсем озверели. В 1.5.2 точно не было. (Хм, а может я просто не замечал?)